# Windows Explorer copying time benchmark

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark our company os, one of the steps is calculate how much time does it take to a user to copy something to somewhere with a mere ctrl-c/ctrl-v under explorer.
So I'd like to know how to scriptize that action in a batch to be ran several times so I can get the time execution, specifically how to make the copying process popup appear. I think "rundll32 shell32.dll" is involved somehow but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may either

- use the **Windows User Interface Automation** API ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation ) directly from your application;
- or you may create an **AutoIt** script ( http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ )

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with vbscript.  See the script examples on the [Folder.CopyHere method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.  Interestingly, the `Folder.CopyHere` method also works to put files into a zip folder.  Look at [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028897/1683264) (if for no other reason than to see another real-world example of how to employ `CopyHere`).  Unlike the `scripting.filesystemobject` copy function, the `shell.application` copyhere function uses the Windows UI API, prompting for replace if exists and showing the file copy dialog as if the user dragged-and-dropped.

Here's an example benchmark.vbs that copies `".\Ubi Caritas.mp3"` to `%temp%` 100 times, then shows the time in milliseconds the operation took (with 4-digit precision).

```
set wShl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
tmp = wShl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
set wShl = nothing
set oShl = CreateObject("shell.application")
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set srcfile=fso.GetFile("Ubi Caritas.mp3")
dest=tmp & "\" & srcfile.Name

wscript.Echo "Testing copy speed from " & srcfile.Name & " (" & srcfile.size & " bytes) to " & dest

' single copy
msb4 = Timer
call doCopy
msafter = Timer
wscript.Echo "1 copy took " & FormatNumber(msafter - msb4, 4, -2, -2, false) & " seconds."

' 100 copies
msb4 = Timer
for i = 0 to 100
    call doCopy
next
msafter = Timer
wscript.Echo "100 copies took " & FormatNumber(msafter - msb4, 4, -2, -2, false) & " seconds."

set destfile = nothing
set oShl = nothing
set fso = nothing

sub doCopy
    oShl.namespace(tmp).copyhere(srcfile.Name), 16
    if isEmpty(destfile) then set destfile = fso.getFile(dest)
    do until destfile.size = srcfile.size
        wscript.sleep 10
    loop
    destfile.delete
end sub
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>cscript /nologo benchmark.vbs
Testing copy speed from Ubi Caritas.mp3 (2929371 bytes) to C:\Users\me\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\Ubi Caritas.mp3
1 copy took 0.0664 seconds.
100 copies took 4.0430 seconds.
```

Comment: Hi Rojo, your script is not working.. I created the same enviroment you described (with the mp3 file) but it gives me "file not found" error on line 32 `if isEmpty(destfile) then set destfile = fso.getFile(dest)`, can you give it a look please? thanks

Comment: Try changing the second line to an absolute location.  `tmp = "C:\Users\[your username]\Appdata\Local\Temp"`  That's the destination.  You can change the source file by modifying `set srcfile=fso.GetFile("[full path here]")`.  Or you could use `wscript.arguments(0)` and `(1)` to pass the source and destination on the command line.

Comment: I should also mention that in my case, the file copied so quickly that I never saw the file copy progress bar.  You should either use a larger test file than I did or make your source and destination different drives (i.e. copy from a network drive, or copy to a USB flash drive for example).