# Difference between manual deletion and deletion by a script?! (bat or vbs)

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, delete-file

I am currently trying to automatically delete files of a program, while running the program. The program does recognize the changes if I delete the files manually in Windows, but *not* if I delete the files with a script.

All files get deleted, though. I tried a bat and a vbs script, executed the scripts manually and/or by a call from within the program - always with the same result: manual deletion is recognized, scripted deletion not. I should mention that it is important for me that I can call a script/executable, which automatically deletes the files, from LUA 4.0.

What exactly happens if I delete a file in Windows and in which way is it different to the deletion by a script? Is there a way to 100% emulate the windows deletion routine? Or is there some secret 'folder got updated'-flag, which I don't know of? The natural folder properties `DateLastAccessed` and `DateLastModified` get updated.

For the sake of completeness here are my scripts (they delete any existing file fitting to `*Random*.level` and remove empty folders):

BAT:

```
REM delete all "Random" maps
del /S *Random*.level
REM remove empty folders
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /S /B /A:D ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

VBS:

```
' create shell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
' get current path
strPath = objShell.CurrentDirectory
' create file system object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' delete all random level files
ProcessSubFolders oFSO.GetFolder(strPath)


Sub ProcessSubFolders(oFolder)
    ' get all files in the folder
    Set cFiles = oFolder.Files
    ' for every file
    For Each oFile In cFiles
        ' check if it's a level file and has "Random" in its name
        If Right(oFile.Name, Len(".level")) = ".level" And InStr(oFile.Name, "Random") Then
            ' if true delete it
            oFile.Delete
        End If
    Next

    ' process all subfolders in the same manner
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        ProcessSubFolders oSubFolder
    Next

    ' if folder is empty
    If oFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 And oFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        ' delete it
        oFolder.Delete 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: both scripts should delete files the same way as "manual" delete does. Please post the code supposedly not "recognizing" the deletions.

Answer (score 4):

The `Shell.Application` object is capable of performing filesystem actions as though they were [manually initiated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120431/1683264).  For example, the `Folder.CopyHere` method allows the creation of zip files by copying files into them as [Windows Compressed Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028897/1683264).  You see the file copy progress bar and everything.

So by extension, it stands to reason that using the same `Shell.Application` object to perform your file deletion would behave the same as a manual file deletion.  Here's a short JScript script I wrote to test my theory:

```
var shl = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var items = shl.NameSpace("c:\\users\\me\\desktop").Items();

for (var i=0; i<items.Count; i++) {
    if (/\.tmp$/i.test(items.Item(i).Name)) {
        WSH.Echo('deleting ' + items.Item(i).Name);
        items.Item(i).InvokeVerb('delete');
    }
}
```

... which deletes *.tmp from my Desktop.  Unfortunately, as it is, for each .tmp file it encounters, I get a confirmation window dialog asking, "Are you sure you want to send this file to the Recycle Bin?"  On cursory investigation, the [only workaround I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409765/1683264) is, instead of deleting the files, move the files to a temporary folder, then delete the folder.  I'm not sure whether that would satisfy your conditions or not, but I think it's worth experimentation.